# MATLAB-SIMULINK GUI interaction

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to create a MATLAB GUI that will display the result of an ADC in SIMULINK. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8U39.png) is a picture of the setup I have in Simulink. I use a Display block to output the ADC. I want the value of the Display block be passed to a label I have in my GUI. I use the code:

```
get_param('Simulink_ModelSim/Power1','value')
```

but an error appears. I don't understand what is happening. When I pass 1 bit with a switch, it goes well. but with displays it does not. Please Help. TIA

Comment: Display block does not have a value parameter. When you want to plot live values from Simulink, it is better to write a MATLAB s-function interface.

Comment: Hi Navan. I only want to display the value on a static text in my GUI. I tried  a Manual Switch with: get_param('Simulink_ModelSim/Manual Switch,'sw') and it displays the output of the switch.  Is that not possible for any other sink component?

Comment: Are you displaying a live value when the simulation is running or a static value at the end of simulation? If it is a static value at the end of simulation consider using sink blocks like "To Workspace" or "Outport" that logs their data in the workspace. You can read that data and use it in your GUI.The switch param is just giving you its "on" or "off" position value. Not your output data value.